# How can I set the gdb command timeout in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

I'm using VS Code to debug a c++ program. Sometimes the debugger will hang when I type an inappropriate debugger command, for example, printing an un-initialized variable (a `shared_ptr`, which causes a wait of several minutes). In this case, I have to wait for a very long time or restart the program. I'm wondering if I can set a timeout for debugger commands.

I'm using VS Code remote debug mode (the program runs on a remote SSH machine).

Comment: @ks1322 there are other ways to get the debugger hang, for example, call a method which does't exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try setting GDB's `remotetimeout` setting in your VS Code launch config, which you can do by inserting the following into the VS Code launch config:

```json
"setupCommands": [
    {
        "text": "set remotetimeout <num>" # TODO pick a <num> value.
    }
],
```

From [GDB's docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Configuration.html):

> Set the timeout limit to wait for the remote target to respond to *num* seconds. The default is 2 seconds.

From the VS Code launch config `setupCommands` field description:

> One or more GDB/LLDB commands to execute in order to setup the underlying debugger. Example: "setupCommands": [ { "text": "-enable-pretty-printing", "description": "Enable GDB pretty printing", "ignoreFailures": true }].